# Why never any notification of moderator elections?

Tags: feature-request, election

Perhaps my absence from meta is the issue here: I *very* rarely spend time on meta; what time I do spend on gamedev is devoted to teaching i.e. answering questions on the regular site.

I haven't once been notified of the opportunity to nominate / vote in a moderator election, in spite of having been active here for 7 years and on the site frequently through that period, even when not actively answering questions.

Can anyone say why it is that I'm always notified of stackoverflow elections  via the regular site - I also don't spend any time on meta there - but never of the ones for our site? It is rather frustrating.

Is this is a feature that is lacking on gamedev, specifically? Do others get notified; if so, how?

Comment: I can't say why you haven't been notified but I'm pretty sure I've seen a news [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) on the main site during the last election.

Comment: If you consult [this page](https://stackexchange.com/users/104686/arcane-engineer?tab=inbox) (I hope it's the right link, I can't see what's in there), do you see the notification "election" on October 23?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I do see two notifications there for Oct 23 & Oct 30 2017. What I'm having difficulty believing is that I could have failed to see them at that time. Not a week goes by when I'm not on SO/SE. If that was the case, and the notification was at all clear (red icon on inbox), I'd have seen it and voted at once.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I don't recall the case for the GDSE election, but I do recall seeing the red dot icon on my in box for my SO election notice.

Answer (score 2):

You should get notifications (viewable via the “inbox” icon in the top navigation bar) for elections on any SE site where you are eligible to participate. I have two at the top of my list for the StackOverflow election right now. I am fairly sure I had similar notifications for Gaming as well, since I voted in that election (but don’t visit the site all that regularly).

There are also “event” banners in the community bulletin UI for the site, above where feature meta questions appear. Often there will be featured meta questions as well, especially as the election goes on.

I can see it being pretty easy to miss these (particularly the inbox notifications, if you visit infrequently and get a lot of *other* notifications in the interim), so I think there is an argument to making elections more of a special-case, obvious notification elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, currently for SO, I see a notice for the current election cycle when I mouse over my inbox. But when I view all my messages, it doesn't show up as a proper message that I can click & read. Maybe this is a "feature"?

Mouse over view:

[image]

View all messages view:

[image]

Comment: It is _very_ easy to miss the notices in the “all items” view.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I agree, however my point is that even if I do happen to notice it, I cannot open the election notice in that view. Unlike the other messages, there's no message link & no description - it just says 'election'. That's why I suggested it might be a bug.

Comment: Yeah, I think so too.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I've [posted it as a bug over on SO meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364931/cant-open-election-message-in-view-all-messages-mode). Guess we'll see where that goes.